# Three level mapping in AWS CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How can I create and use a three-level map in mappings section in CloudFormation templete?

`Fn::FindInMap`  can be used only for two-level map. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html

Want to determine resource type based on cellName, domain, and realm.
Something like:

```
Mappings:
  ElastiCacheNodeTypeMapping:
    cell1:
      beta:
        us-east-1: cache.m6g.large
        us-west-2: cache.m6g.large
        eu-west-1: cache.m6g.2xlarge
      prod:
        us-east-1: cache.r6g.24xlarge
    cell2:
      beta:
        us-east-1: cache.m6g.large
        us-west-2: cache.m6g.large
        eu-west-1: cache.m6g.large
      prod:
        us-east-1: cache.r6g.24xlarge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I create and use a three-level map

Sadly, you can't. This is **not supported** as you already noticed. The only way around it could be maybe through CloudFormation [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html). You would have to create such a macro, which would take your three-level map, and re-organize it into a valid two-level map for stack deployment.

Comment: In my case, the attributes cellName, domain and realm will be passed as parameters. Even if I'm able to create a two-level map, creating composite key is going to be messy. This is because I can't use ``Fn::Join`` or ``Fn::Sub`` in ``Fn::FindInMap``. :(


Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html#w2ab1c33c28c26c13

Comment: @RohitLakhotia It does not matter. you can't have 3 level maps.

Comment: @RohitLakhotia CFN is not the most user-friendly tool. It lacks a lot of things that other IaC tools (e.g. Terraform) have. As I wrote you could make macro for that, or re-design your architecture so that these 3-level maps are not needed. CFN custom resource also could be used.

Comment: @RohitLakhotia You could also have a look at the CDK tools to create or deploy your CFN stacks. CDK has a lot more flexibility.